# Azure Web App MySQL In App throws error

Tags: mysql, azure, phpmyadmin

I was closely following this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/) to enable MySQl into web app that contains NodeJS application. But upon enabling the MySQl it throws below below error.

[image]

And also when performing the Kudu [instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/#kuduconsole) I am getting access denied. even though I am putting the correct credentials found in the file MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.

Answer (score 1):

Change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in config.inc.php

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
The reason for this is that pma tries to connect to the mysql.socket if you use localhost. If you use 127.0.0.1 PMA makes a TCP connection which should work.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find `config.inc.php` file?

Comment: If you are using Node.js check config.js file and make necessary change, i am attaching sample config.js file below.

Answer (score 0):

Check config.js file below and make necessary change,

```
// config.js
const config = {
 app: {
   port: 3000
 },
 db: {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 27017,
   name: 'db'
 }
};

module.exports = config;

// db.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config');

const { db: { host, port, name } } = config;
const connectionString = `mongodb://${host}:${port}/${name}`;
mongoose.connect(connectionString);

// app.js
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./config');

const app = express();
app.listen(config.app.port);
```